# How do I create a 3 column layout and keep the middle column centred

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin

I am writing a Xamarin app where I have a table of 3 columns and multiple rows.

```
  some text | + | some text
a different | + | blah blah blah
       text | + | more and more
```

Column 1 and 3 will contains various text strings which change length.  Column 1 should be right justified, column 3 should be left justified.  The middle column is a Drawable which contains a graphic that should line up with the next row and therefore should always be centred (the example above shows all the + lined up).

I am using a BaseAdapter<>, with the custom view containing a LinearLayout with TextView/ImageView/TextView as the 3 columns.

I've tried various combinations of gravity, layout_gravity & layout_weight, but the middle column always seems to move.

Any suggestions on how to keep the middle column centred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for your cell layout. Adjust the weights (making sure they always add up to 100) to adjust the column widths.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:text="Left text"/>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="40">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:text="Right text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The middle column is now lined up.  Thanks.